# Add line break to generated CST node

Tags: rascal

I am modifying a CST tree in order to add information in it like this
`` (EvoQuery) `<Status s> <QlQuery q>`; ``

But I'd like to have a line break between the Status and the QLQuery. When I try this :
`` (EvoQuery) `<Status s> \n <QlQuery q>`; ``

Rascal marks a syntax error. What is the proper way to format a CST node ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to introduce newlines in concrete syntax is by writing it literally, just like in string template syntax:

```
(EvoQuery) `<Status s>
           ' <QlQuery q>`;
```

Compare to the string template syntax:

```
str x = "<s>
        ' <q>";
```